# A connected graph where every vertex has degree 2 is a simple cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Intuitively it seems the case that if and only if $G = (V,E)$ is connected finite graph where $|V|\geq 3$ and every vertex of $v \in V$ has 2 neighbours, then $G$ is a simple cycle. However, how would one go about proving such a statement?

Comment: I would try proving the contrapositive. If $G(p,q)$ is not a simple cycle, show that some vertex has either less than 2 neighbors or more than 2.

Comment: It's not true unless $V$ is finite.

Comment: @TheoBendit. I am fine with assuming $G$ is finite. Thanks - updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

By induction on the number of vertices.

- One vertex of degree two : the graph is necessary a loop. Done.
- More than one vertex : choose one vertex, the two incident edges are distinct (otherwise your vertex has just a loop and is not connected to the rest of the graph). Merge these two edges, erasing the vertex. The merged graph is still connected, still has degree two at every vertex, hence is a loop by induction. Hence you had a loop before merging.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a vertex $v_0$. It has two neighbors; let us call them $v_1$ and $v_{-1}$. In turn, $v_1$ has two neighbors, one of them $v_0$, and we can call the other $v_2$. Similarly, $v_{-1}$ has two neighbors, one of them $v_0$, and we can call the other $v_{-2}$. Continuing in this way in both directions, we get a two-way infinite list of vertices:
$$
\ldots, v_{-3}, v_{-2}, v_{-1}, v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots
$$

where there is a vertex $v_n$ for every integer $n$, and its two distinct neighbors are $v_{n-1}$ and $v_{n+1}$.

Because the graph is finite, there must be some distinct $i$ and $j$ such that $v_i = v_j$. Picking these so that $|j - i|$ is minimized, we find a list of vertices
$$
v_i, v_{i+1}, v_{i+2}, \ldots, v_{j-1}
$$
such that these are all distinct. (They are all distinct because if they weren't, say that $v_{i'} = v_{j'}$ in the above list, and we get a smaller value of $|j' - i'|$, contradicting minimality of $|j - i|$.)

Now the above list of vertices is exactly a cycle, because $v_i$'s neighbors are $v_{i+1}$ and $v_{j-1}$, and $v_{j-1}$'s neighbors are $v_{j-2}$ and $v_i$. Also, no other vertex has an edge to any of $v_i, \ldots, v_{j-1}$, because they have only two neighbors; thus $v_i, \ldots, v_{j-1}$ is a [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) of the graph; since the graph is connected, by definition it has no nontrivial cuts, hence $v_i, \ldots, v_{j-1}$ is the entire graph.

Comment: Why construct an infinite list of vertices if we know $G$ is finite? Also, you argue that if we can find a connected subgraph within $G$, then it is clear that this subgraph must be $G$ itself. I don't really see how this follows.

Comment: @YungJohn_Nash The infinite list is just a way of proving it that I liked. You could do it with a finite list but I like the elegance of the map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$. The latter thing was slightly misstated, good catch, I will edit. It's because a connected graph can't be split into two disconnected pieces.